# Using the io.webfolder.cdp.command.DOMDebugger (and examples) in Chrome Devtools for Java

Tags: java, google-chrome-devtools, protocols, chromium, devtools

I'm using the Chrome DevTool Protocol for Java (V3.0.1) API with the Chromium browser (v  67.0.3396.99 on Windows 7)

Has anyone worked with using the DOMDebugger to set breakpoints when certain events are fired?

I'm trying to get the io.webfolder.cdp.command.DOMDebugger to set breakpoints on events (such as hashchange) so that during execution, I can trap any change to the 
Window's location hash and carry out a set of operations prior to resuming execution

So far, I've had little luck with getting the io.webfolder.cdp.command.DOMDebugger to set breakpoints on events using 
       domDebugger.setEventListenerBreakpoint("hashchange");
       or using, domDebugger.setInstrumentationBreakpoint("hashchange");

Where and how do I define the eventlisteners for those events? What happens when breakpoints are hit during execution.

Also, I do not see related events such as  DebuggerBreakpointResolved, DebuggerPaused or DebuggerResumed being fired.

If anyone has done any related work on this, could you please post some explanation nd same examples. The sample examples listed at 
https://github.com/webfolderio/cdp4j#samples does NOT have examples on using the DOMDebugger

Comment: any luck or thoughts on this? im trying to retrieve changes via websocket on chromedebugger, but very hard(new) topic.